# Traffic is not coming to newly replicated pods in hpa kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, hpa

I have created HPA object for my deployment. Once the target CPU is reached, new pods are spinning up. But when i look for the CPU usage, it still stays at `0m` and no traffic is going to the new pods. What may be root cause for this issue?

Comment: Hello @Ramanichandran. Could you share your HPA and deployment yaml configs? Also, does it stay that way or is just happening for some time after the scale-up?

Comment: Hi @WytrzymałyWiktor, Thanks for your reply, i have added the yamls. Actually the traffic is going to the first pod only, it stay that way only. After the first pod limit is exhausted the connection is getting dropped

Comment: Hello @Ramanichandran. Can you make sure that the configs are correct? I see you mentioned the service mapping but the HPA's `scaleTargetRef.name: pid-dm-rd-guad` is different from Deployment's `spec.template.spec.containers.name: pid-dm-rd-guacd` so Service might not point to them.

Comment: yes @WytrzymałyWiktor, thanks there was issue with sessionaffinity paramter in service which was not allowing to divert traffic to newly created replica. We found out later

Comment: Hello @Ramanichandran. Glad it's working now. I have made a community wiki answer for you for better clarity. Feel free to mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a community wiki answer posted for better visibility. Feel free to expand it.

As mentioned in the comments, the issue was with with `sessionAffinity` parameter in the service spec which was not allowing to divert traffic to newly created replicas.